# How does one define a var that could be one of two objects?

Tags: ios, swift, types, any

Real simple, I have two button types that vary slightly. I'm trying to create a variable that can handle both type at a later time in the code. Something like this:

```
var button: Any

If(condition one)
   button = NavButton()
else
   button = IconButton()
```

My buttons have unique functions for setup. As a crude example:

```
button.setup(name: String)
button.setup(int: Int)
```

When I call them, the superclass / protocol doesn't recognize them.

How is this done best? Or is this not done using a single variable? I'm building a factory class that is virtually identical in function save ONE call and ONE parameter.

Comment: Having two subclasses with different arguments to the same function name doesn't make a lot of sense; you are going to need some logic to determine which function to invoke on a given instance so you may as well have two different functions e.g. `setupWithString(String)` and `setupWithInt(Int)` and then you will have no problem with using a single superclass. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: That was it. I wasn't sure what was normal. It's been a while since I've written this sorta code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious way is to declare it as UIButton, assuming both are actual buttons.

```
var button : UIButton
```

Comment: Ok my problem is that each button type has unique versions of a single method. setup(name: String) vs setup(int: Int). When I try to call the subsequent call on button.setup() it throws and errors due to the unknown uniqueness. I'll update the above to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is what Paulw11 mentioned. I needed to create two unique super functions for each of my parameter types. Probably obvious to most of you, but if not, there's the answer.

I created a protocol, then extended that into a super class with two functions. I think used the super class as an initial type, then changed them in subsequent lines, the gated the unique methods.

```
protocol MyButton {
    func setupString(s: String)
    func setupInt(i: Int)
}
public class CustomButton: UIButton, MyButton {
    func setupString(s: String) {}
    func setupInt(i: Int) {}
}

class ButtonString:CustomButton {
    override func setupString(s: String) {}
}

class ButtonInt:CustomButton {
    override func setupInt(i: Int) {}
}
```

Then gated their use like so:

```
var myButton: CustomButton = CustomButton()

if(string) {
    myButton = ButtonString()
    myButton.setupString("Hello World")
} else {
    myButton = ButtonInt()
    myButton.setupInt(42)
}
```

Hope this helps someone.